# how to handle nulls gracefully in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a situation where I have to copy values from one object to another. For each field the copy statement is wrapped with the following snipped of boilerplate code:

```
if (a.getC() != null) {
   b.setC(a.getC());
}
```

I had a look at Guava `Precondition.checkNotNull(...)` but it still throws NPE which I'm trying to evade.

How can I do that in a more natural way?

Comment: It isn't checking a or b for null.

Comment: Is it a problem if the value set by `b.setC` is null? If not, you don't need the null check. The only way this code would throw a NPE is if `a` or `b` was null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache commons-lang3 offers this:

```
b.setC(ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull(a.getC(), b.getC()));
```

But I have to admit that I'm not sure if this would really be an improvement.

Comment: that fits my needs. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a method using var args that checks all the args for your `if` statement:

```
public boolean argsNotNull(Object ... objs) {
    boolean b = true;
    for(Object o : objs) {
        if(o == null) {
            b = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
if(argsNotNull(a)) {
    Object c = a.getC();
    if(argsNotNull(b, c)) { // A null 'c' object may be valid here, depends on your logic
        b.setC(c);
    }
}
```

Since this method uses var args you can feed it as many args as you want, but it will not work with primitives in its current state.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem of `null` checking. It just delegates it to a different method.

Comment: @Jeffrey OP asked for more natural.  This isn't as nice as say the Groovy [safe navigation operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator(?.)), but it is better than the alternative of (`a != null && b != null && c != null`) or vast, non-specific try/catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Is the **b.C** value supposed to exactly reflect what is in **a.C** ? In that case if **a.C** is null then **b.C** whould be null, and you don't really need a null check.

Otherwise, to avoid curley braces you could do something like this :

```
b.setC((a.getC() == null) ? b.getC() : a.getC());
```

This assumes that the getter and setter from b match up exactly. If C from a is null then **setC()** from **getC()** which effectively does nothing.